# Single VectorDrawable of many becomes blurry upon losing focus

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

I have two Fragments side by side. The left side is a list of customer names with a search bar, and the right side is a page for the customer details. In the details fragment, there is a grid of items containing VectorDrawables.

[image: normal]

When I type into the search bar, the "assignation log" VectorDrawable blurs, but no other one does:

[image: blurred]

And when I close the keyboard, the VectorDrawable unblurs itself:

[image: unblurred]

I thought it may have something to do with losing focus, since it unblurs when closing the keyboard, but interestingly, the image doesn't blur when the keyboard opens. It only blurs once I type something.

It also blurs when I click that red 'x' icon on the very left. Clicking that opens an AlertDialog with some information. It unblurs when the dialog is dismissed.

[image: dialog]

I'm not sure what's going on. It affects only the one VectorDrawable, so it must have something to do with that. But its attributes are largely identical to the "reports" VectorDrawable:

VectorDrawable assign.xml:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:height="200dp"
    android:width="200dp"
    android:viewportHeight="24"
    android:viewportWidth="24" >
    <path android:fillColor="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:pathData="M19,3h-4.18C14.4,1.84 13.3,1 12,1c-1.3,0 -2.4,0.84 -2.82,2L5,3c-1.1,0 -2,0.9 -2,2v14c0,1.1 0.9,2 2,2h14c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2L21,5c0,-1.1 -0.9,-2 -2,-2zM12,3c0.55,0 1,0.45 1,1s-0.45,1 -1,1 -1,-0.45 -1,-1 0.45,-1 1,-1zM12,7c1.66,0 3,1.34 3,3s-1.34,3 -3,3 -3,-1.34 -3,-3 1.34,-3 3,-3zM18,19L6,19v-1.4c0,-2 4,-3.1 6,-3.1s6,1.1 6,3.1L18,19z"/>
</vector>
```

VectorDrawable reports.xml:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:height="200dp"
    android:width="200dp"
    android:viewportHeight="24"
    android:viewportWidth="24">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:pathData="M19,3h-4.18C14.4,1.84 13.3,1 12,1c-1.3,0 -2.4,0.84 -2.82,2L5,3c-1.1,0 -2,0.9 -2,2v14c0,1.1 0.9,2 2,2h14c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2L21,5c0,-1.1 -0.9,-2 -2,-2zM12,3c0.55,0 1,0.45 1,1s-0.45,1 -1,1 -1,-0.45 -1,-1 0.45,-1 1,-1zM14,17L7,17v-2h7v2zM17,13L7,13v-2h10v2zM17,9L7,9L7,7h10v2z"/>
</vector>
```

Also, opening a dialog or opening the keyboard and typing on the right-side fragment does not blur it, only on the left-side fragment.

Comment: What happens if you switch the two vector drawables? such that reports comes as the rightmost icon?

Comment: also can you drop in your gradle configuration? I suspect they are not actual vectors but pngs. And its trying to draw a lower resolution image

Comment: do you solve your question ? can you share ?